# REGEXP in PHP to catch specific domain links

Tags: php, regex

So I'm working on a regexp to catch all links in a string, meaning wordsthat start with with a protocol like http, https etc, words that start with www. or words that end in some specific domains, ".com", ".hr" and ".net".
But somehow this regexp I made always returns all the links that start with a protocol, but only the last one of those that end in a specific domain. 
What am I doing wrong :|? Many thanks!

```
$description='test.com test2.hr http://www.test3.hr https://test4.com test3.net';
$pattern = '/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]|(?:\b((?:[\w]+\.com$)|(?:[\w]+\.hr$)|(?:[\w]+\.net$)))/i';
preg_match_all($pattern, $description, $out);
var_dump($out[0]);
```

Comment: Just to clarify, this is only successfully matching the last three URLs in `$description`, right?

Comment: Yes, and if u remove the last url, it only matches the last "two" then.

Comment: What about removing the `$`s: https://regex101.com/r/rR6rR4/1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your original regex. First, you should be treating the protocol with the conditional modifier `?`. I'm not sure why you're using the second block of `[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]` or why you're using the `|` operator after that; if there's a specific reason, please let me know. Finally, `$` only works as end-of-string when you use it at the very end of the regex; otherwise, you should use `\Z`, which matches end-of-string at any point in the regex, although I don't think you want to be matching end-of-string in here anyway. I've rewritten the regex below in the way I think you want it to work:

```
$description='test.com test2.hr http://www.test3.hr https://test4.com test3.net trash string don\'t match test4.net';
$pattern = '/(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/(?:www|ftp)\.)?[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*(\.[A-Z]+)/i';
preg_match_all($pattern, $description, $out);
var_dump($out[0]);
```

returns:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "test.com"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "test2.hr"
  [2]=>
  string(19) "http://www.test3.hr"
  [3]=>
  string(17) "https://test4.com"
  [4]=>
  string(9) "test3.net"
  [5]=>
  string(9) "test4.net"
}
```

Comment: and if the domain is .org ?

Comment: Well to be honest I found the first part of the REGEX somewhere, and, with my limited knowledge, tried to edit it to my liking. 
Many thanks :)

Comment: @LeoStarić if you want to be more permissive with TLDs, as @PedroLobito suggests, you could use something like `/(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)?[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*(\.[A-Z]+)/i` would be better and more expandable.